# Question about different datetime format, really confusing

Tags: amazon-web-services, datetime, utc, cron-task

This question is probably better to explain with an example date, for instance the datetime now (London time): 21/08/2020 11:34 am

I'm confused about the time with 'ET' and also UTC format, and ISO format, is EDT same as ET?
Why so many different format and they are sooooo confusing. Can someone explain in a simple way, the information online is not very easy to understand unless I didn't find the right documentation.

The reason I want it to convert ET to UTC is because AWS cron job only take this format (please correct me if I'm wrong) Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you are right. `AWS Cron job takes only UTC timestamp`.

[UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) and [GMT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenwich_Mean_Time) are different ways of tracking time. [EDT(ET)](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/et) both are same. You can read about ISO vs UTC [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58847869/utc-vs-iso-format-for-time), nicely explained here.

To covert one timestamp to other one, you can use [this](https://savvytime.com/converter/edt-to-est).